# button changes a label different view controllers

Tags: objective-c, xcode5.1

How to change label "Time" in viewcontroller 2 by pressing button 1 in viewcontroller 1

I know it's a basic question but I'm learning the language by myself and I'm new to it

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First create property and synthesize "label" of viewcontroller 2.
2. instantiate viewcontroller 2 class in viewcontroller 1 in the action of button 1 or in view didload.
3. access synthesized label by viewcontroller 2 instance.
4. set whatever value you want to that label in viewcontroller 1 so that your viewcontroller 2 will get changed value.
5. Finally when you come to viewcontroller 2 you will see changed value.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is through [`NSNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html).